# Click "More" in Android Option Menu

Tags: android, optionmenu

When there's more than 6 items in the Android Option Menu, a "More" will be in place. My question is currently I see two different behaviors upon clicking, from different apps. One will show a menu like  [this](http://developer.android.com/images/menu_design/MenuDiagram.png), another will show a context menu like [this](http://developer.android.com/images/menu_design/ContextMenuDiagram.png).

Which is one is the proper Android way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the "proper" way as in the default behaviour you get. I don't think the difference is meaningful, but to achieve the second the coder must have mucked around, and I don't think it's worth it..

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how those two are related. Your first link shows the options menu with "more", which is what you were talking about in your first sentence. The second link shows the context menu after a long press on a list item - that's a completely different item. They both have their uses.

The menu is used for options that are global to the current activity. The context menu is intended for options that relate to the specific item you picked.

If you see an app that uses a context menu for "more", then it's not using the normal Android menu system. I've even seen Google apps use that (Maps, I believe), and I don't know why you would do that.

Comment: If the number of items in your menu vary, but you always want a More, then you have to hack it like in Google Maps. Why would you want to, I don't know either, except for "the boss asked me to"

Comment: Yeah, I don't like writing your own custom UI because "I think it's cooler". Like Google Currents did. What's the point? It's bound to break if a new version of Android introduces a new UX. Besides, it's nicer when all apps adhere to the same design guidelines. The Android API has a good system for menus with any number of options, so why not just use it?